# Add Export Log feature to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

Would anyone else be interested in having a feature that would allow for exporting the chat log, in part or whole?

Useful options could be:

- Export current buffer.
- Export all since your last message.
- Export last 24 hours.
- Export all between [select dates & times].
- Export entire log.
- Export to TXT
- Export to CSV
- Export to XML

Comment: I'm struggling for reasons why *not* - but what would be the motivation here? What scenario would this be helpful for?

Comment: @Marc Although I'm sure this is an isolated one:  At RPG.se, we sort of run a D&D4E game in two chat rooms.  It would be nice to be able to export the log there for offline preservation, or transfer to other sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can bookmark conversations (slices of room transcripts) already, and save the page if you want a copy.

You'd also have to make the legal considerations... if someone's going to consume chat transcripts as XML into a program, are they really going to follow the CCSA license on the content? It's not public domain after all.

Comment: I must have missed something in the ToS here.  How is the content of our conversations in a publicly-viewable chat room not public domain?

Comment: @Iszi - I think what @Dan is saying is that it is public but *under cc-wiki licence* (attribution etc), just like SO.

Comment: Public domain means free of copyright. The content of our conversations in the chat room is not free of copyright. The ToS clearly says that anything you post on SO will be made available by them under a Creative Commons license. This license places several important restrictions on the use of that content. If you slurp it into a bot and post the transcripts online somewhere without meeting those requirements, you are infringing the copyright and can be sued. This ToS is linked in the footer of all parts of SO, including the "legal" link on the chat rooms.