# Unanswered questions counting against accept rate

Tags: support, accept-rate

**Before you vote to close:**  Yes, I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16902/152399) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) - and no, they don't help.

I just noticed my "Accept Rate" on Meta today is *horrible*.  Before reviewing my questions, accepting one answer, and deleting a "closed as duplicate" thread, my rate was around 30%.  Now, I've gotten it up to 50% but that still didn't seem right.

Then, I took a closer look at the questions I have here.  There's 9 in all, only 4 of which have any answers.  So, of course my "Accept Rate" would be around 50% of all the questions I've posted - but even that didn't seem just.

Next, I started writing this question and got the above-linked question in the "Related Questions" box.  I started reading through, and it still appears to me that my current "accept rate" is not correct.  Of my 9 questions, every question that has been answered has an accepted answer.  So, my "Accept Rate" should be 100%

Additionally frustrating is that the majority of my unanswered questions are [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) - but that is another issue.

I haven't yet tested this on any of the other sites, but will be following up on it shortly.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem right. I see 9 questions (excluding this one), 4 of which have answers, and only 2 of them are accepted answers. So by my calculations, that's 50%, which is what I see as your accept rate.

Comment: My general advice is just to ignore "accept rate police". If you don't get a good answer to a question, you shouldn't accept one. Plain and simple. If you *do* get a good answer, you already know to accept it. Problem solved.

Comment: I also think this is weird. If you ask a question that's too hard or esoteric for anyone to answer, that's not the same as simply not accepting a perfectly good answer to a question. My accept rate on SO is 90% even though I've accepted 100% of my answered questions, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, my "Accept Rate" should be 100%

You didn't accept any answer on following 2 questions at the moment, so it will not be 100% as you expected.

[Add Export Log feature to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70330/add-export-log-feature-to-chat)

[Secure Wiki Oneboxes don't link to secure Wikipedia pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82342/secure-wiki-oneboxes-dont-link-to-secure-wikipedia-pages)

Comment: This should be it. On top of it, remember that if you hover over your accept rate, it tells you exactly how it's getting that number. And in this case, it's saying "2 out of 4 eligible questions", which falls in line with this answer.

Comment: I don't understand: if you have 4 eligible questions, and you accept two of them... that makes it 50% acceptance? two is to four like x is to 100... **YOU must be very good at math**.

Comment: @Aleadam, I don't know. I am **weak** at math actually. But 2/4 is .5 => 50% to me, No?

Comment: @YOU not everyone has a PhD in theoretical math around here :P. One last question: can you explain me why he got two upvotes for this?

Comment: @Aleadam, hum, no idea, but Hans Passant's comment about "Nobody cares about accept rate at meta" is a bit amusing and that could lead to casual upvotes to him too.

Comment: I see what I was missing, now.  The shading-in of the number which indicates a question has an accepted answer is *very* subtle to my eyes.  I'd thought that any number that had a block around it indicated the question had an accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could post an answer to your own questions and accept it. It wouldn't be too inappropriate as long as you had something constructive you've discovered while waiting for answers.

Comment: This would only be useful if I *had* an acceptable answer to the question.  In the case of [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request] items, acceptable answers generally can only come from the devs.